# Select document field with parameter in elasticsearch update by query API

Tags: elasticsearch, field, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-painless

ElasticSearch version = 5.5

I've inherited some code that updates arbitrary document fields via the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) to an arbitrary value like this:

```
{
 "query": ...
 "script": {
   "inline": "ctx._source." + field + " = " + value + ";"
   }
 }
```

This occasionally causes the query to fail due to the maximum compilations per minute circuit breaker.

A [partial update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document) would work well for this case, but as far as I can determine, partial updates are only supported in the standard update API, not the update by query API:

```
{
 "query": ...
 "doc": {
   field: value
   }
 }

Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [doc]
```

At least, being an ES newb, I assume that's what that error means. There's also no mention of `doc` in the update by query API docs.

Assuming I'm right that partial updates won't work, parameterizing the script as recommended in the [scripting guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params) seems like the next step, but there doesn't appear to be any way to access a source field specified by a parameter:

```
# I wouldn't expect this to work, but tried anyway
{
 "query": ...
 "script": {
   "inline": "ctx._source.params.field = value;",
   "params": {
      "field": field,
      "value": value
      }
   }
 }

"caused_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}}
```

Trying to access the field via [doc-values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) also doesn't seem to work:

```
{
 "query": ...
 "script": {
   "inline": "doc[params.field] = value;",
   "params": {
      "field": field,
      "value": value
      }
   }
 }

caused_by":{"type":"null_pointer_exception","reason":null}}
```

Is there any way to fix this script or is a more extensive refactor required?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right, [partial updates are not supported](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20135) by the update-by-query API (+ [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/24898)).

You've almost found the right way to do it, though, which is like this:

```
{
 "query": ...
 "script": {
   "inline": "ctx._source[params.field] = params.value;",
   "params": {
      "field": field,
      "value": value
      }
   }
 }
```

**UPDATE:**
As of ES 6, replace `inline` by `source`

Comment: My god, I have been looking for this example for 5 hours. Thank you for the first working example!